# WCF Data Service + Expiring Data (Timer?)

Tags: .net, iis, caching, timer, wcf-data-services

I would like to expose a few endpoints via a WCF data service (Singlton) which will maintain a collection of data used to respond to individual requests.

Ideally I would like to be able to expire (delete) the data held in memory for a given request after a period of time.

The stored data would be used to build (partially only, so out of the box caching is not ok) a result set to return to the client. The data will be objects from an API and must be kept in memory, not peristed to storage.

I'm looking for ways to trigger the 'purge' process to check for expired data. Kicking off a timer in the ctor seems like a bad idea. It could be run for every request (single concurrency in enabled) but this seems excessive, and would potentially leave data hanging around when there are not more requests?

Any thoughts at all on the issue appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up redesigning and hosting the relevant service component in a windows service with a system timer to purge required data.

Answer (score 0):

You need some sort of timer to run the cleanup process on a regular interval.  You could trigger on request but that's not advisable because you certainly shouldn't block requests on what could be a long running cleanup process and because you could potentially have long periods of times between requests means the requests could be working off data that's beyond it's lifetime.

One option is to not make the cleanup process not critical by making the reads filter data out beyond it's lifetime.  For example, you could use an in memory database like SQL Compact Edition or Sqlite.  The cached data could have a timestamp column on it and then reads into the cache could query and always filter by timestamp not older than X.  What that does is it makes it *not critical* for the cleanup to happen but instead an optimization for memory pressure that really should happen.  Sql just gives you easy mechanisms to filter by timestamp.  You could do the same with your own in memory data structures.

As far as the cleanup process goes, you need some sort of timer or something to kick it to run.  The process the starts the WCF in proc service could also start a timer and call into the cache on a periodic basic to clean it up.  If a cleanup call gets called while its cleaning up, it would just return.  If you make the cleanup not critical (like outlined above) and the cleanup process is ignored if running, then each request could potentially kick it as well.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. I hear what you're saying but unfortunately the object I will be storing don't contain only static data so persisting them to a db (unless my understanding of SQLCE/Lite is way off) is not an option, but storing the object's is not any issue. Custom container class + LINQ = :). My issue is the triggering of the process. As you pointed out the timer would work. I was of the understanding that the Timer kicks off it's handler on a different thread, leading to possible race condition for a singleton service looking at it's persisted data collection...